# Pandas - group by quantile position

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with the following structure:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "value": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0],
        "group": ["A"] * 6 + ["B"] * 6
    }
)
```

I would like to obtain a new dataframe, with the same number of rows, that has, for each row the quantile that corresponds to the value in the group.

For this case, the output would be like this:

[image]

There can be a very large number of groups and values on completely different scales, and each group may have different sizes.

Comment: A quantile is a division of a dataset into k pieces. If you don't define k, this question is incomplete. If k is the length of the group, then you just want the rank within the group, right (maybe divided by length of the group)?

Comment: yeah, the rank in a 0-1 scale

Comment: But quantiles have nothing to do with splitting into k pieces https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function

Comment: The actual definition of what I'm looking for is the cumulative distribution function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function, I just explained it in a very cumbersome way

Comment: I know, but with empirical data this is equivalent to sorting and splitting it into k bins. My point still stands that a quantile function requires a parameter of how many pieces you need (quartile, decile, quintile, etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "value": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0],
        "group": ["A"] * 6 + ["B"] * 6,
    }
)


def norm_group(group):
    g_min = group.value.min()
    g_max = group.value.max()
    group["quantile"] = (group.value - g_min) / (g_max - g_min)
    return group


print(df.groupby("group").apply(norm_group))
```

seems to do the trick:

```
    value group  quantile
0       0     A       0.0
1       1     A       0.2
2       2     A       0.4
3       3     A       0.6
4       4     A       0.8
5       5     A       1.0
6       5     B       1.0
7       4     B       0.8
8       3     B       0.6
9       2     B       0.4
10      1     B       0.2
11      0     B       0.0
```